# How to know tile is empty

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-2.x

I have created a tile map of 8x8 matrices,where each tile having sprite.
After deleting a sprite from a tile,the upper sprite will take the position of deleted sprite,for that how to find the tile is empty in cocos2d-x 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Step : 1

Create separate class for your tile map.

Create object for the class and assign the proper value for tile status.

Step: 2

Declare new titeArray and add the sprite into titeArray...

For example

```
 TileData *tile = [[TileData alloc] init];
 sprite.userObject = tile;
 [tileArray addObject:sprite];
```

**In touch function**

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   for (int i = 0; i < [tileArray count]; i++) 
     {

        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [[tileArray objectAtIndex:i]  boundingBox], touchLoc)) {
           //Game logic like remove your tile or do some functionality.
        }
     }
}
```